# Laravel Spark with braintree

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

please help me. I am new to laravel spark. How to add custom fields in payment method in spark with brain tree, like adding customer name, cardholder name, cvv etc. In that payment method only card number and expiration date fields are available to use.

See the image below:

[image: See the image link below]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CVV and address verification in your Braintree settings.

If you log in to your Braintree control panel, and navigate to Settings -> Processing, you can enable these checks under 'Fraud Tools'.

[Braintree Control Panel - Fraud Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaB9Q.png)